# get specified line from text using readline method

Tags: c#

I want to get a specified line from text using ReadLine method

Here is my code

```
for (int p = 0; p < 100; p++)
{
    var files = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(logid.Text + ".txt");
    var lines = await FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(files);
    var pattern = sm.SelectedItem.ToString();
    var sline = lines[p].Contains(pattern);

    lv.items.add(lines[sline]);
}
```

The problem is `var sline` is not converted into int so lines cannot read it.

The actual program is to add text only from line contained pattern from a selected combobox.

Comment: there is no code that may suggest a conversion between string and int. please specify

Comment: @SteveB I think the int is only needed for the index

Comment: I think "var lines" should be outside the loop

Comment: Try: `lines[p].IndexOf(pattern);` or if that string does contain the pattern.. do you want to use `lines[p]` instead?

Comment: actually everything should be defined outwith and just use "if (lines[p].contains(pattern))"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is you need to search the list for the line matching pattern. Your code just looks through the first 100 lines and sees if any of them contains the text you want. the Contains() method returns a bool - not a string.

I'm not entirely sure why you're looping to 100 arbitrarily? Is the file you're reading always going to have exactly 100 lines? I think your are looking for more something like this? You can drop the loop completely.

```
var files = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(logid.Text + ".txt");
var lines = await FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(files);
var pattern = sm.SelectedItem.ToString();

// try to look up a line in the list the has the pattern we're looking for in it.
var targetLine = lines.FirstOrDefault(line => line.Contains(pattern));
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(targetLine))
    lv.items.add(targetLine);
```

if you may have more than 1 line matching the pattern, you will want to iterate over all of those results using linq's Where().

```
foreach (string line in lines.Where(line => line.Contains(pattern))
    lv.items.add(line);
```