# How to create a SecondaryTile?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I created this method to insert into StartScreen a SecondaryTile, but I get an exception when I try to retrieve the string of the saved file and insert it into a URI

```
    private  async void AddStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
          StorageFile x= await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("Immagine.png", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

//muss.Immagine is a web url
          Uri uri = new Uri(muss.Immagine, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
          BackgroundDownloader downloader = new BackgroundDownloader();
          DownloadOperation download = downloader.CreateDownload(uri, x);
          await download.StartAsync();

          string uriString = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("Immagine.png").ToString();
          Uri newww = new Uri(uriString);
          SecondaryTile tile = new SecondaryTile("OpenArte", "Open ARTe of Italy", "Open ARTe of Italy", "15", TileOptions.ShowNameOnLogo, newww);
          await tile.RequestCreateAsync();    
    }
```

I get an exception when I create the Uri "newww".
 this is the Exception:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.UriFormatException' occurred
>   in SYSTEM.NI.DLL
>
> Additional information: Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not
>   be determined.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that your problem is that `GetFileAsync("Immagine.png").ToString()` is not returning a valid URI. Check the value of that statement.

Comment: How could I do to turn it into a string?

Comment: If you are accessing local storage you can use something like "ms-appdata:///local/Immagine.png"

Answer (score 0):

`...LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("Immagine.png").ToString();` will always return the same result similar to `"...IAsyncOperation<StorageFile>"` because by default `ToString` returns type name (and result is of type `IAsyncOperation<StorageFile>`).

I'm not exactly sure what you trying to achieve, but you may need to read content of that `StorageFile`. Additionally you need to `await` result of the function to actually get `StorageFile` object - [How to get a file using WinRT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11060697/how-to-get-a-file-using-winrt) and [get specified line from text using readline method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13841863/get-specified-line-from-text-using-readline-method).